# tampering with the very DNA nucleic alphabet that spells out your daily health narrative

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of this sentence? I completely don't understand it.

Sleep loss will leak down into every nook and cranny of your physiology, ***even tampering with the very DNA nucleic alphabet that spells out your daily health narrative***. And at this point, you may be thinking, “Oh my goodness, how do I start to get better sleep? What are you tips for good sleep?

Source : https://www.ted.com/talks/matt_walker_sleep_is_your_superpower/transcript#t-44349 (13:20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**the very DNA nucleic alphabet**" refers to the scientific convention of notating nucleotides in genetic material with the letters [G, C, A and T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_sequence).

A narrative is a story, so "**your daily health narrative**" would be the story of your daily health.  Something like *"I woke up and felt weak.  I ate breakfast and felt better.  I sneezed and coughed..."*

Saying the nucleic alphabet spells out your daily health narrative is a rather stretched kind of metaphor, or use of poetic license.  Clearly the letters G, C A and T would not be sufficient to spell out a proper story in English, but because alphabets make up words and words make up narratives, it just about works as a conceptual metaphor.

Overall, therefore, the meaning of the sentence is:

> Sleep loss will leak down into every nook and cranny of your physiology

- Sleep loss is bad for you, physically

> even tampering with the very DNA nucleic alphabet

- It can even damage your DNA

> that spells out your daily health narrative

- which will make you feel unhealthy on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: I completely symphathize with myself when "I completely don't understand it." before @@